# Can I use Stack Overflow's reengineered WMD editor?

Tags: discussion, markdown, editor

I hope this isn't an outrageous question. I'm developing a Web application that is going to be sort of like a blogging platform, but aimed towards storing snippets of code. I have read the [blog posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/updated-wmd-editor/) about the effort to improve the WMD editor. The reengineered code is available on GitHub, but there doesn't seem to be any info about whether/how it's licensed.

Is it OK to use it in my app or would that be messed up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While there isn't a license present in the [main repository](http://github.com/cky/wmd/tree/master), the [most active fork](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master) is released under the MIT license. There is, however, one issue that prevents free and clear use and distribution of these files: the original, minified version was *never actually released* under any open source license. The [author's website](http://wmd-editor.com/download) says that the *next* version will be open source, but it doesn't say anything about the *current* version. I doubt you'll have a legal problem here, but you should have all the facts.

And if you want to be 100% legit, just [download and use](http://wmd-editor.com/downloads/wmd-1.0.1.zip) the current version from the author's site.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/wmd/ it says the license is MIT, when I go to download, there is a direct link to the .zip file. To the layman who doesn't dig any further into the original website the license it is under is MIT.

Comment: @X-Istence - Keep in mind that the original author didn't add the code to the google repository.  While the person who did may have had permission from the original author to do so, and perhaps even to re-license it under a license the author did not originally apply, the lineage is still someone murky.  The risk is probably small, but it's important to understand and recognize it so one can make reasonable decisions.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine if they made it available on github that it would be available for you to use on your own projects.

Answer (score 0):

[The most active branch](http://github.com/ananthakumaran/wmd/)
[v2 download page](http://github.com/ananthakumaran/wmd/downloads)