# Post textbox plugin

Tags: discussion, editor, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use Stack Overflow's reengineered WMD editor?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/can-i-use-stack-overflows-reengineered-wmd-editor)

Could anyone please tell me what is the textbox (any plugin etc.) used throughout StackOverflow for posting questions/answers? This editor looks quite good, and, if it is open source, I'd like to use it.

Comment: Oh thanks, I got the name of the editor and its URL :)